# Set interval between breaks on time axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

First let's create some example data. The times are stored using `lubridate`'s `hm` as this seems the most suitable.

```r
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

(
  data <- tibble(
    Time = hm('09:00', '10:30'),
    Value = 1
  )
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Time         Value
#>   <S4: Period> <dbl>
#> 1 9H 0M 0S         1
#> 2 10H 30M 0S       1
```

Here's how I'd like the plot to look. For now I've specified the breaks manually at half-hour intervals.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(data, aes(Time, Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_time(breaks = hm('09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30'))
```

[image]

**I'd like to create these breaks automatically at half-hour intervals.** Trying to use `scales::date_breaks` gives an error.

```r
ggplot(data, aes(Time, Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_time(breaks = date_breaks('30 mins'))
#> Error in UseMethod("fullseq"): no applicable method for 'fullseq' applied to an object of class "c('hms', 'difftime')"
```

Trying to create the breaks using `seq` also gives an error.

```r
seq(hm('09:00'), hm('10:30'), hm('00:30'))
#> Note: method with signature 'Period#ANY' chosen for function '-',
#>  target signature 'Period#Period'.
#>  "ANY#Period" would also be valid
#> estimate only: convert to intervals for accuracy
#> Error in if (sum(values - trunc(values))) {: argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using new `breaks_width()` function from the package `scales`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(Time, Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_time(breaks = scales::breaks_width("30 min"))
```

Answer (score 12):

The error message you got, dealing with a method `applied to an object of class "c('hms', 'difftime')"`, should give you a clue that there's a class issue here. First thing to do is check the class of your times, and check the docs (`?hm`), both of which will show you that `hm` actually returns a period object, not a datetime.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

class(data$Time)
#> [1] "Period"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "lubridate"
```

So you need to change `Time` into a `Date` or similar object. There are different ways to do this, but I just quickly pasted today's date and `Time` together, then converting to a datetime object. The date I used doesn't matter if you don't actually need a date; it's basically a dummy for creating the object you need.

You also want `scale_x_datetime` rather than `scale_x_date`. Without setting a `date_labels` argument, you would have labels like "`2018-05-28 09:00:00`", so you can format those as just times by giving a formatting string to `date_labels`.

```r
data %>%
  mutate(time2 = paste(today(), Time) %>% as_datetime()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time2, Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = scales::date_breaks("30 mins"), date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-28 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks @camille, that works nicely although it seems strange to have to translate the times to a date/time. N.B. I originally used `scale_x_time` not `scale_x_date` as you suggested in your final paragraph.

Comment: I agree it's strange. There might be a way to make a time-only object rather than datetime, but I don't know of one

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to transform your `Period` object into `POSIXct`, which then allows you to use `scale_x_datetime` and the `date_breaks` argument, e.g.

```
data %>%
  mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(Time, origin = "2018-01-01", tz = "GMT")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "30 min", date_labels = "%H:%M")
```